# How do I use the IsNull() expression in Ms Acess

Tags: ms-access-2013, isnull

I am trying to write a query where the output should be invoices that is outstanding (not paid yet or not paid in full) to be sent out to clients. Currently my query (in SQL view) looks as follow:

```
SELECT Main.Reference, Main.Date, Main.Company, Main.[Claim No], Main.Invoice, Main.[Amount Paid]
FROM Main
WHERE (((Main.[Amount Paid])<[Invoice])) OR IsNull()
ORDER BY Main.Company;
```

The IsNull function is calling for an expression in the brackets and I don't have a clue as to what should go in there. Basically the output (report) should show invoices that has been paid but not in full (paid lesser amount than the actual invoice amount) or not paid at all. Currently it gives me a report, but it shows invoices that has been paid but shows unpaid on the report.

Comment: Why did you add the tag `mysql`  ?

Comment: The [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/isnull-function-f963233b-1c1e-4b0c-8bc3-3e8c0ea67c61) give a impression on how to use `IsNull()`.   I think (but I am not an Access expert, you can use `WHERE (((Main.[Amount Paid])<[Invoice])) OR IsNull(Main.[Amount Paid])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
WHERE [Amount Paid] < [Invoice] OR IsNull([Amount Paid])
```

or (pure SQL):

```
WHERE [Amount Paid] < [Invoice] OR [Amount Paid] Is Null
```